# split string with equal sign at any location using python

Tags: python, regex, string

I would like to split string with equal sign at any location.

`[In] This is a example string abc=xyz this is a example string`

Can somebody please tell me how to print all the string after the equals to sign ("="). For instance, in the above case, output should be

`[Out] abc=xyz`

I got some clue how to split if ('=') if its in last word but not in anywhere inside string.

Comment: @EdChum that's not the output OP wants. OP's output and question is not really the same

Comment: You say you want to split a string, but your sample input/output instead shows locating a string that has an `=` in it.  I'm voting to close this question.  Please clarify what you want, show us what you've coded, and what's going wrong.  Also see [ask]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

findall to find all the occurances, (I assumed that was your requirement)

```
import re
a = "[In] This is a example string abc=xyz this is a example string"
print(re.findall("\w+=\w+",a))
```

**OP**

`['abc=xyz']`

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes, depending on his requirement

Comment: `[word for word in 'This is a example string abc=xyz this is a  example string'.split() if '=' in word]` would do the same without needing a regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
s='This is a example string abc=xyz this is a example string'
l=s.split('=')

print(l)
```

Output:

```
['This is a example string abc', 'xyz this is a example string']
```

So you want `l[-1]` to get the last item or `l[1]` to get the second item

EDIT: If you want to find the "word" that has a `=` in it then

```
s='This is a example string abc=xyz this is a example string'
l=s.split()
l = [word for word in l if '=' in word]
print(l)
```

Output:

```
['abc=xyz']
```

Comment: That's not what OP wants in terms of his output. His question and output doesn't match